# What is referred to as a "video pub"? Is that just any bar?

Tags: word-meaning

I read on https://www.livinginperu.com/news-4184-law-order-peru-new-alcohol-laws-established-in-lima-peru/ ([mirror](https://archive.vn/ixH9v)):

> The new decree, Decree N°180, allows the sale and consumption of alcoholic beverages during the stated hours in: casinos, nightclubs, video pubs and reception halls.

What is referred to as a "video pub"? Is that just any bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some pubs and bars advertise the fact that they have video (television) screens, for example for showing sports events. The quoted words might be distinguishing pubs with video from pubs without.